# long long VS 2013 Release Win 64 wrong result

Tags: c++

When I try this code in VS 2013/Win64/Release, I get the wrong result: it prints `1 1`.

In Visual 2013 Win32/Debug/Release & Win64/Debug, the result is correct.

The Visual Studio project was created with default parameters.

```
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   long long inc[2] = { 0, 1 };
   long long dinc[2] = { 0, 0 };

   dinc[0] = inc[1] - inc[0]; 
   dinc[1] = inc[0] - inc[1]; //expected -1 ==> display 1

   for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
       std::cout << i << "\t" << dinc[i] << "\n";

   return 0;
}
```

How can this result be explained?

Comment: See if optimization is turned on for Release mode. `Right-click project-->Properties-->C/C++-->Optimization-->"Optimization" option`

Comment: I just ran that code with `Optimization` disabled, and I got the correct results

Comment: I can reproduce this locally. Seems the optimiser messes up somehow...

Comment: That's one helluva compiler bug.

Comment: For anyone who wants to take a look here is the disassembly for x64 using /O2: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/08d190131b51bd11

Comment: It is an optimizer bug on auto-vectorized code.  Fixed in VS2015.  A workaround is /arch:SSE

Answer (score 1):

Disable optimization for your project in `Release` mode for `x64`

`right-click on Project-->Properties-->C/C++-->Optimization-->Disabled`

`Configuration` at top left of property window should be set to `Release`
`Platform` at top right should be set to `x64`

EDIT:
With a temporary variable in the middle to hold `inc[0] - inc[1]`

```
long long total = 0;
total   = inc[0] - inc[1];
dinc[1] = total;
```

the correct values are printed with `Optimization Enabled`, for whatever its worth

Comment: This gets rid of the problem but why on earth would you want a release build to not be optimized?

Comment: To properly answer this question it should explain why the optimizations are doing this.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I've had issues in the past where evaluations in code were inexplicably being handled incorrectly until optimization was turned off. I'll update my answer once I track down the root cause.